# arithmetic overflow error n(umeric to numeric ) datatype

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @val1 numeric(22,6)
declare @val2 numeric(38,15)= 12345678912345678912345.12

set @val1=convert(numeric(22,6),@val2))

select @val1
```

It's throwing an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

I've tried both cast and convert but same got the same error.

Comment: 12345678901234567890123.12 requires numeric(25,2) at a minimum

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @val1 numeric(22,6)
declare @val2 numeric(38,15)= 12345678912345678912345.12

set @val1 = convert(numeric(22,6),@val2)

select @val1

numeric(p,s)
```

/*
p (precision)
The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

s (scale)
The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.*/

As from the defintion you would understand the error.

`@val1 numeric(22,6)` means that you can store up to 22 digits, from which 6 would be decimals digits => you can store a number with 16 digits . 6 digits.

The second number has to many values in the left side so SQL would not know how to convert it and throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Because `@val1` accepts data of `NUMERIC` type with a total of **22 digits**, 6 of which are after decimal point, and 16 before the decimal point.

`@val2` has a total of **25 digits**, 23 before the decimal point and 2 after.

You should declare `@val1` as:

```
DELCARE @val1 NUMERIC(25,2)
```

And `CONVERT` using:

```
SET @val1 = CONVERT(NUMERIC(25,2), @val2)
```

Comment: 9 + 9 + 5 + 2 = 25 (there are no zeros in that number)

Comment: You're right, looks like my I've edited my sample data. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

of course converting a `38 digit` number to a `12 digit` is ambiguous, but you can convert them to varchar, do your own logic for convert (by using substring, concat, round, etc) then convert it to numeric:

```
declare @val1 numeric(22,6)
declare @val2 numeric(38,15)= 12345678912345678912345.12

set @val1=cast(substring(cast(@val2 as varchar(55)),1,16) as numeric(22,6)) 

select @val1
```